# Chakra UI with nextjs

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

I am using chakra ui with nextjs and want to json server call. I installed redux, react-redux etc. I created store, reducers, actions, etc but unable to configure store with chakraProvider

```
    <ChakraProvider theme={myTheme}>
       <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
```

like

```
 <Provider store={configureStore({})}>
       <App />
 </Provider>,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set no the _app.jsx file.

likely

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ChakraProvider theme={myTheme}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ChakraProvider>
</Provider>
```